# password salt storing

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, hash, salt

I want to update my password setup that is currently using just MD5.

Now what I would like to do is use something stronger (maybe sha256) with unique salt per user.

The question is about the salt storage.

Do I go with storing the salt in its own column in the database?

Then hash salt + password and when it comes to login, call the salt and password from the database, to make one.

Or do I go the way of making a salt, by using the username, email and timestamp which would also give me a unique salt per user?

I am wondering, if someone got a hold of the database with salt as a column, they would know the salt for each user, then they could crack the password.

Answer (score 5):

The salt is not a secret, it can be stored plaintext together with the hash. It is not even necessary to have a second field in the database. If you look at PHP's `crypt()` function, you can see, that the salt will be included in the hash value itself.

It's the job of the salt, to make already existing rainbowtables useless, because a rainbowtable has to be built for one specific salt. Using a different salt for every hash will prevent rainbowtable attacks, because you would have to create a rainbowtable for each hash. That's why it is not necessary to keep the salt secret.

I would recommend, that if you want to improve your password hash system anyway, you do it right, with a hash function that is slow. The article [password hashes with bcrypt](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_bcrypt) explains the important points of generating a hash for passwords.

- Generate a salt per password, not per user.
- Use a random (unique) salt, not one derrived from other parameters.
- Use a slow hash function.

Last but not least, don't be afraid of doing it correctly, the code of your application can be as easy as your current implementation with MD5.

Comment: How can salt not be secret? If attacker knows the salt, he can easily modify the dictionary attack to include the salt and voila!

Comment: @Martins Briedis - Precalculating all hashes of a certain dictionary is usually called a rainbow table. An attacker could not use already existing public rainbowtables (just googling for the hashed value), because a rainbowtable has to be made exactly for one specific salt (or for the original dictionary if no salt was used).

Comment: @Martins Briedis - Forgot to mention, that building a rainbow table is not a task you do in a few seconds. When you use a slow hash function (like bcrypt) it needs a lot of time, and if you use a different salt for every password, then you need a lot of time for each password.

Comment: @chumkiu - Why, and where would you store the key?

Comment: @martinstoeckli Obviously if it's secret there is more security. We can discuss how much security we gain, but we cannot say that's the same. Personally, I store one salt per project in a config file.

Comment: @Garry - Yes, phpass is one of the most recommended solutions for this.

Comment: @chumkiu Storing one salt per project in a config file defeats the purpose of adding salt.  Every single password generated should have a unique random salt added to it.  Not per user, not per project, every single password generated gets a unique salt.  Rainbow tables are precompiled so that existing hashes can be linked to passwords.  If the intruder knows the salt, they'll have to recompile the entire table just for that individual salt.  When EACH password has a different salt, they'll have to repeat this process for each salt.  Computers are fast, but good god man!

Comment: @BrentLingle I've re-read the old question and answer. So, you would store the salt where? It should be not secret? And if the attacker want just one password? He knows the salt and the pass encrypted.

Comment: @chumkiu - Since this thread is open again, and i just wrote a [tutorial about password hashing](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php), i would invite you to have a look at it. If you want to add a secret to your hashed password, you can use a pepper additionally to the salt, but i would not recommend to mix them up, because they have a different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Forget MD5 or SHA. Use Bcrypt. (Blow Fish Crypt) Comes native with PHP 5.3 and above. (crypt method 2a) it is more secure and processes slower.

When using Bcrypt the salt is stored together with the hash in the same feild . There is no reason for a seperate one.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Comment: Yes PHPass would work. I recommend just using the native php functions above tho if using php 5.3 above

Answer (score 0):

Just reading on another post and someone says the salt is not a secret and can be stored a database column. So that answers my question